# Extract node information from external URL using query

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I want to be able to extract information from specific nodes from an external XML file.  I currently have been trying

```
$contents = file_get_contents('https://experiencehermann.com/post-sitemap.xml');
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom -> loadXML($contents);
$finder = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $finder->query('//loc');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue ."</br />";
}
```

I'm able to use this same technique when I have the XML in the PHP directly but not when pulling from an external source.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The XML contains namespaces, see: [PHP xpath: extract all nodes, even with namespaces](https://serverfault.com/questions/490443/php-xpath-extract-all-nodes-even-with-namespaces) for more info on how this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your query is quite simple, you don't even need XPath, you can simply use the `getElementsByTagName` method on the `DOMDocument` object:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($contents);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('loc');

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeName === 'image:loc')
        continue;
    echo $node->nodeValue ."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I did try that, unfortunately, there's an `<image:loc>` in the XML file also so I get that image information in the result also.  Is there a way to just get the `<loc>` information using getElementsByTagName?

Comment: Ah, of course! I have updated the answer

Comment: I'd still like to learn more about xpath, but this'll work for now.  Thanks

Comment: @WWDesigner You're very welcome and absolutely great idea, XPath is a very powerful tool